# Is it possible to show rows side by side in dandelion datatables

Tags: datatables, thymeleaf, dandelion

I'm using java spring with thymeleaf and dandelion datatables. I want to show dandelion datatables rows side by side. So I want to use  rows divede by 3 rows.Is it possible?How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with the latest release (v1.1.0)